# Minimal round trip time for any given network speed?

Tags: networking, internet, internet-connection, internet-speed

I have network speed of 4 Mbps(Mega bits per sec) at both sides i.e. client and data center side. It means network can deliver max 4 Mbps. So If I have a response of less than equal to 4 Mega bit then it can take up to 1 sec for complete request to response round trip(asuming request is very light). Right ?

Now for the sake of simplicity just assume that response content is of just 1 byte(8 bit). How much time it can take for complete round trip just for the sake
of understanding ?

Can  it be  8/(4*10^6) sec  ?  I believe this may not correct as there will be some minimal time that will always be spent irrespective
of response size. Is that correct ? How much that can be with 4 Mbps considering two hops i.e. browser to Akamai and then Akamai to my data center ? Is 
it function of network speed ? I observed it is around 30-40 ms in my case.

Comment: Every piece of networking hardware between you and your destination will add some latency as well, you cannot assume that the link speed is the *only* cause of latency. While electronic devices are fast they still have to decode, analyse and route packets out on correct interfaces to get to their destination.

Comment: @Mokubai I agree on that part.But please ignore it for now as I am more interested on understanding minimal time for round trip based on stats I provided ?

Comment: Minimal round trip sounds about right to me, but I was trying to get across something about the 40ms you mentioned. While it might *look* like only a couple of hops there might actually be a vast network of VLANs, switches, VPNs and other SDN type devices. Unless you built the network yourself and know that the two machines are physically set side-by-side you can't make assumptions about how "close" they are in terms of network topology.